# How do I fix this async/await function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am trying to get the number of documents in my mongodb collection using async and await. When I run this piece of code I get "TypeError: cb is not a function".

I have tried using promises to get this to work, however I am still inexperienced with this topic and I am still learning how to work with promises.

Here is the call

```
  getFlashCard : function(colName, flashID, callback) {

    var docCount = documentCount();

    console.log(docCount);
   }
```

Here is the function

```
 async function documentCount() {
     const count = await mongodb.collection("Interview  Questions").count();              
     return count;
   }
```

I am getting an error that says " cb(err, val)
    ^

TypeError: cb is not a function
    at runInAsyncScope
"

Comment: This would be hard to answer without more info. Try providing the full stack trace for the error. Where is cb defined?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dont need `async` and `await` for this because its already an promise. Just add an `then` on the end:

```
 mongodb.collection("Interview  Questions").count().then(count => {
 console.log("counted: " + count)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

`documentCount()` is an `async` function.  As such, it returns a promise.  All `async` functions return a promise.  So, the way you get a value out of a promise is the same as with any promise.  You use `.then()` or `await` on it.  So, in `getFlashCard()`, you could do something like this:

```
getFlashCard : function(colName, flashID, callback) {

    documentCount().then(docCount => {
        console.log(docCount);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

This assumes that you're using your `mongodb.collection().count()` properly and that it returns a promise.  If that's not the case, then you will also have to fix that (I don't personally know mongodb).

FYI, it appears you created `documentCount()` hoping to turn an asynchronous value into a synchronous value.  You can't do that in Javascript.  While `await` suspends execution within a function and lets you appear to write more synchronous looking code for asynchronous operations, it doesn't work across a function boundary.  You cannot change an asynchronous value into a synchronous value in Javascript.  So, anyone who wants to use the `docCount` value will have to deal with it asynchronously as I've shown above in `getFlashCard()`.

Comment: @nathananderson - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.  If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.